# Can containerized tools run against a local machine?

Tags: docker, containers

I conduct security testing on programs and applications. Often, when I want to run a tool, I need to add libraries and other dependencies onto the system that I'm testing in order for the tool to work properly. Also, the test environment doesn't have internet access, which makes installing these dependencies more difficult.

I was thinking about containerizing multiple tools so that I could put them onto the systems that I'm testing and they will have all of their dependencies. I am considering doing this in Docker, so anytime you see a reference to a container it implies that it's a Docker container.

Some of the tools I would like to use are nmap, strace, wireshark, and others for monitoring network traffic, processes and memory.

My questions are:

1. Can I run these tools "locally", or will there be networking required, as though they are coming from a different machine?
2. Is there anything required to put onto the test system for the container to run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker allows you to connect to devices on the host itself [using the `--privileged` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

Additionally you can add the `--network=host` flag which means [your docker container network stack is no longer isolated from the host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

using the flags above should allow you to run your tools in docker without additional requirements on the host (other then a Docker runtime + your docker container).

However, it does mean you need to load your Docker container into the host. Normally downloading a docker container requires networking. But what you can do is tar a docker image with [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and import that tar with [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response and proactively addressing further issues!

Answer (score 0):

Docker is, first and foremost, an isolation system that hides details of the host system from the container environment.  All of the tools you describe need low-level access to the host network and process space: you actively do not want the isolation that Docker is providing here.

To give two specific examples: without special setup, you can’t `tcpdump` the host’s network interface, because a container has its own isolated network stack; and you can’t `strace` host processes because a container has its own process ID space and restricted Linux capabilities that disallow it.

(From a security point of view, also consider that anyone who can run any `docker` command can trivially root the host, and there is a reasonably common misconfiguration to publish this ability to the network.  You’d prefer to not need to install Docker if you’re interested in securing an existing system.)

I’d probably put this set of tools on a USB drive (if that’s allowed in your environment) and run them directly off of there.  A tar file of tools would work as well, if that’s easier to transfer.  Either building them into static binaries or providing a `chroot` environment would make them independent of what’s installed in the host environment, but also wouldn’t block you from observing all of the things you’re trying to observe.